# avi mp4 flv video player

Tags: plugins, video-player

I want to uploads videos from admin and show them  using any video player.
I used a plugin but when i tried uploding a  video the message appers that uplod size exceeded.
Can anybody suggest me any good video player plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to increase your media upload limits in your php.ini file or ask your host to increase them.

You can also increase the limits via your functions file or .htaccess file.

Installing a video plugin won't increase the limits.

You can also use the native video player already included in WordPress without the need to install a plugin.

Paste the full URL to the video on its own line in your text editor.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I edited php.ini the changes become effective after apache is restarted.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing your upload limit is the way to go. please increase it by editing your PHP.ini file or by asking your web host's support to do it for you.

To know your upload limit, go to wp-admin then to media then to add media and you will see right below the uploader "upload limit: xx MB"(xx being the upload limit in megabytes)
There is a neat video layer that comes with jetpack which you ought to consider seeing that jetpack also gives you a  number of other awesome functions that you would otherwise have had to install plugins for.

if you like I could increase the limit for you and install jetpack for you to ensure everything works fine now and in the future. please get in touch with me